# An integral identity involving cotangents and Bessel functions

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, integration, bessel-functions

Numerical experiments suggest that the following integral identity holds for Bessel functions of the first kind,
$$J_2(t) = 12 \int_0^{1/2}\mathrm{d}x\,\cot \pi x \int_0^x \mathrm{d}y\, \cot \pi y \, J_0(ty)\big[J_0(tx)\,J_0(t(1-x-y))-J_0(t(1-x))\,J_0(t(x-y))\big],$$
but so far I have been unable to prove this. Does anyone have a suggestion how to go about this?

Note that by symmetry one could equivalently drop the second term in the brackets and extend the range of $x$ to $(0,1)$, but then one should take the principal value of the integration.

Comment: remarkable identity; to order $t^2$ both sides of the equation indeed give $t^2/8$.

Comment: Have you tried to replace each occurence of $J_2$ and $J_0$ by their expression as a contour integral?

Comment: Difficulty is that with most expressions of the Bessel functions as integrals or series, one cannot straightforwardly interchange the order of summation/integration due to divergence of the cotangents. The same problem occurs when attempting natural functional transformations of the identity in the variable $t$.

Comment: I tried to show that the RHS satisfies the ODE of the Bessel function, but with no luck :(

Comment: @Timothy Budd : since we are dealing with convergent integrals, there must exist non-singular integrands with the right change of variables, it's just that it may convert into Integrals on infinite domains, like the half-line, but then this would transform the problem into studying limits, which is usually more tractable. Something involving asin may help.

Comment: With the integral representation of the Bessel function $$J_{2}(t)=\frac{2^{5} t^{2}}{ 3 \pi} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos^{3/2}(\theta)}{\sin^{5}( \theta)}\sin\left(t-2 \theta+\frac{\theta}{2}\right) e^{-2\ t \cot \theta} d\theta$$ (as found in, e.g., Gradshteyn & Ryzhik) one can get rid of the outer integral and compare the inner integral with  (essentially)  the integrand of this formula.

Comment: @JohannesTrost This is an interesting representation exhibiting a cotangent, but I am not sure I understand how this can be used to get rid of the outer integral. You are not claiming that the $\theta$-integrand of your representation agrees with the $x$-integrand of the identity, are you?

Comment: After transforming the integration variable to $x=\theta/\pi$ you have a $\int_{0}^{1/2} dx$ , so everything else (except the $\cot \pi x =\cos(\pi x)/\sin(\pi x)$, but including the prefactors) has to be equal to the inner integral. (Sorry for the shortness. Comments are just too short.)

Comment: Using the change of variable $\theta=\pi x$ and making $12 \cot (\pi x)$ appear we get an expression for the $y-$ integral. (oops Johannes already answered).

Comment: Sorry, but I still do not understand. That the definite integrals agree, does not mean that the integrands do.

Comment: Indeed, but to check or rule out that $\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} 12\cot (\pi x) [A_t(x)-B_t(x)] dx=0$ seems simpler than checking the initial relationship.

Comment: @TimothyBudd And indeed, numerical check shows, the integrands are _very_ different.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With hindsight the identity is not that magical: the Bessel functions play only a secondary role, in the sense that there is a more general identity for arbitrary differentiable functions $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$, namely
\begin{align}
&12 \int_0^{1/2}\mathrm{d}x\,\cot \pi x \int_0^x \mathrm{d}y\, \cot \pi y \, f(y)\big[f(x)\,f(1-x-y)-f(1-x)\,f(x-y)\big] \\
&= -f(1)\,f(0)^2+ 2 \int_0^1\mathrm{d}x\int_0^{1-x} \mathrm{d}y\, f(x)f(y)f(1-x-y).\tag{1}
\end{align}
Substituting $f(x) = J_0(t\,x)$ and using the Laplace transform $\mathcal{L}\{J_0(t\, x)\}(\xi) = (t^2 + \xi^2)^{-1/2}$, we find that the double convolution integral satisfies
$$\int_0^1\mathrm{d}x\int_0^{1-x} \mathrm{d}y\, J_0(t\,x)J_0(t\,y)J_0(t(1-x-y)) = -\frac{1}{t}J_0'(t).$$
Together with $J_2(t) = -J_0(t)-2 J_0'(t)/t$ and $J_0(0)=1$, this reproduces the claimed identity
$$J_2(t) = 12 \int_0^{1/2}\mathrm{d}x\,\cot \pi x \int_0^x \mathrm{d}y\, \cot \pi y \, J_0(ty)\big[J_0(tx)\,J_0(t(1-x-y))-J_0(t(1-x))\,J_0(t(x-y))\big].$$

Let's see why (1) holds. For this it is convenient to introduce the integral
$$I(\epsilon):=2\int_\epsilon^{1-2\epsilon}\mathrm{d}x\int_\epsilon^{1-x-\epsilon} \mathrm{d}y\, f(x)f(y)f(1-x-y)$$
with $0<\epsilon <1/4$.
The meat of the argument is [Hermite's cotangent identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%27s_cotangent_identity),
$$\cot(\pi x)\, \cot(\pi y) + \cot(\pi y)\,\cot(\pi(1-x-y)) + \cot(\pi(1-x-y))\cot(\pi x)= 1,$$
which after insertion in the integrand and using the symmetry under permutation of $x$, $y$ and $1-x-y$, implies
$$I(\epsilon) = 6\int_\epsilon^{1-2\epsilon}\mathrm{d}x\int_\epsilon^{1-x-\epsilon} \mathrm{d}y\,\cot(\pi x)\cot(\pi y)\, f(x)f(y)f(1-x-y).$$
Since the integrand is symmetric in $x$ and $y$ we can further reduce the domain to
$$I(\epsilon) = 12\int_\epsilon^{1-2\epsilon}\mathrm{d}x\int_\epsilon^{\min(1-x-\epsilon,x)}\!\!\!\! \mathrm{d}y\,\cot(\pi x)\cot(\pi y)\, f(x)f(y)f(1-x-y).$$
Folding the region $1/2< x < 1$ onto $0 < x < 1/2$ via the substitution $x\to 1-x$ gives
\begin{align}
I(\epsilon) =& 12\int_{2\epsilon}^{1/2}\mathrm{d}x\int_\epsilon^{x-\epsilon}\! \mathrm{d}y\,\cot(\pi x)\cot(\pi y)\, f(y)\big[f(x)f(1-x-y)-f(1-x)f(x-y)\big]\\
&+ 12 \int_\epsilon^{1/2}\mathrm{d}x\int_{\max(x-\epsilon,\epsilon)}^{\min(1-x-\epsilon,x)}\! \mathrm{d}y\,\cot(\pi x)\cot(\pi y)\, f(x)f(y)f(1-x-y).
\end{align}
Both $I(\epsilon)$ and the first term on the right-hand side have limits given by the corresponding terms in (1) as $\epsilon \to 0$.
It remains to examine the last integral on the right-hand side. By the change of variables $x = \epsilon\, \hat{x}$ and $y = \epsilon\,\hat{y}$ we see that it has a limit as $\epsilon\to 0$ given by
\begin{align}
&\frac{12 f(1)f(0)^2}{\pi^2}\int_1^\infty \mathrm{d}x\int_{\max(x-1,1)}^x \mathrm{d}y \frac{1}{x\,y} \\
&=\frac{12 f(1)f(0)^2}{\pi^2}\int_1^\infty \mathrm{d}y\int_{y}^{y+1} \mathrm{d}x \frac{1}{x\,y} \\
&= \frac{12 f(1)f(0)^2}{\pi^2} \int_{1}^\infty \frac{1}{y^2}\log\left(\frac{y+1}{y}\right) = f(1)f(0)^2.
\end{align}
This finishes the proof of (1).

Comment: Well done! I still find it noticeable in that $J_2$ pops up alone, without any t-dependent factor.

Comment: perhaps not magical, but certainly impressive!